# How to use an elevation without disappearing an component in a constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently developing an application using android-studio with Kotlin.

I want to use the elevation function to a view in a constraint layout with overlap design.

When I add the elevation function to the view, the elevation works but a component overlaps on top disappears. (like view_1 → view_2)

In the like this case, How can I use the elevation function without disappearing the component?

---

view_1

[image]

view_2

[image]

---

Here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="32sp"
               />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Android Studio : 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case simply add the same elevation to your second view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:textSize="32sp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Both of your views got the same elevation so no one is overlapping the other.

**It will look like this:**

[image]